# ¿Cómo filtrar elementos en React?

Tags: reactjs

Hola estoy practicando React y deseo filtrar elementos por categoría pero no es tan sencillo como parece, tengo el siguiente componente que muestras un numero de celulares:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icon from '../assets/Icon';
import './css/product.css';

class Product extends Component{
  render(){
    const { id, imagen, modelo, precio, stock } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="product" key={id}>
        <img loading="lazy" src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${imagen}`} alt={modelo} title={modelo} />
        <h3>{modelo}</h3>
        <h4>$/. {precio}</h4>

        <div id="quantity">
          <button>
            <Icon iconName="fas fa-plus" iconStyle={{padding: "0"}}/>
          </button>
          
          <div id="count">{stock}</div>
          
          <button>
            <Icon iconName="fas fa-minus" iconStyle={{padding: "0"}}/>
          </button>
        </div>

        <button className="add-to-cart"><Icon iconName="fas fa-cart-plus" iconTitle="Añade un producto al Carrito" iconStyle={{padding: "0"}}/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Añadir al carrito</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Product;
```

A continuación el componente que renderiza el componente anterior

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Product from './Product';
import Filters from './Filters';
import celulares from '../../json/celulares';
import NotFound from '../assets/NotFound';

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allProducts: celulares,
      categoryCheckboxes: [
        {
          marca: "Blackberry"
        },
        {
          marca: "Huawei"
        },
        {
          marca: "LG"
        },
        {
          marca: "Motorola"
        },
        {
          marca: "Nokia"
        },
        {
          marca: "Samsung"
        },
        {
          marca: "Sony Xperia"
        },
        {
          marca: "Sony Ericsson"
        },
        {
          marca: "Xiaomi"
        },
        {
          marca: "ZTE"
        }
      ],
      productVisible: true,
      activeFilter: []
    }
    this.onFilterChange = this.onFilterChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      activeFilter: this.state.allProducts
    })
  }

  onFilterChange(){
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),checkboxesChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), select = document.querySelector("select"), range = document.getElementById('set-range-prize');

    this.setState({
      productVisible: true
    })

    select.removeAttribute('disabled');
    range.removeAttribute('disabled');
  
  if (checkboxes.length === checkboxesChecked.length){
    this.setState({
      allProducts: celulares
    })
  }

  else if (checkboxesChecked.length !== 0){
    var updatedList = this.state.allProducts;
    let categorys = this.state.categoryCheckboxes.map(x => x.marca.toLowerCase());

    updatedList = updatedList.filter(item=> {
      
    if (item.modelo.toLowerCase().indexOf(categorys) !== -1){
      return item
    } else {
      console.log("Producto no encontrado")
    }
      
    })

    this.setState({activeFilter: updatedList});

  } else {
    select.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    range.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    this.setState({
      productVisible: false
    })
  }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <aside className="edit-products">
          <Filters changeElements={this.onFilterChange} />
        </aside>
        <section className="products">
        { this.state.productVisible ? this.state.activeFilter.map( x =>{
          return (
            <Product key={x.id}
            imagen={x.imagen} modelo={x.modelo} stock={x.stock} precio={x.precio} />
            )
          })
          : <NotFound text="Ninguna casilla ha sido marcada..." />
        }
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

El problema es el siguiente: Cuando se de click en el boton APLICAR FILTROS, dependiendo de la casilla o casillas marcadas me debe mostrar esos productos pero no me retorna nada, pueden ver la app desde el sgte [enlace](https://husdady.github.io/simulador-de-compras/) . Pueden ver los archivos de la app desde este [github](https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras/) . Tengo entendido que para filtrar elementos, se debe usar `filter` en un arreglo, y hacer que los nombres de todos los celulares mostrados se comparen con la categoria de cada checkbox que esta activado. Me estoy complicando en retornar los productos dependiendo de la categoria activada. Entonces como puedo filtrar por categoria en todos estos productos? Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: ¿Cómo se supone que esto funcione? `changeElements={this.onFilterChange}` no está en uso en `<Filters>` o pasado a los niños.

Comment: Habia olvidado actualizar los archivos en github, puedes ver los componentes aqui: https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras/tree/main/components/main .

Comment: bro ya no te preocupes, lo pude resolver :)